# SQL class problem using Script to solve for and compare factors

Tags: sql, sql-server

Professor wants us to write a SQL script in SQL Server Management Studio something that will result in:

```
Common factors of 10 and 20
---------------------------
1
2
5
```

And use the modulo `%` operator in the code. I've started - am I going in the right direction?

```
DECLARE @CommonFactors TABLE
                       (
                           ID int Identity,
                           Number10 Int default 10,
                           Number20 int default 20
                       )

(SELECT 
     Number10 % ID AS RemainderOF10,
     Number20 % ID AS RemainderOf20
 FROM
     @CommonFactors)

PRINT 'The common factors of 10 and 20 are'

IF (RemainderOF10 = 0) AND (RemainderOf20 = 0)
Print
```

Comment: You can create a table variable, but you need to insert rows in it before querying against it, like INSERT @CommonFactors (ID) values (1),(2),(3),.... but you can use a while structure in order to insert a variable number of numbers.

Comment: Yes, the module operator should be used, but in the where clause, not select.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a Recursive CTE. It is a little clumsy, but it works.

```
with 
M as (select 10 as X, 20 as Y, 1 as I),
N as (select X,Y,I from M union all select X,Y,N.I+1 as I from N where I<X)
select I from N where (100*X/I) % 100 = 0 and (100*Y/I) % 100 = 0
```

The result is

```
I
1
2
5
10
```

If you want to rule out the factor equal to the smallest number, just add the filter at the end of the query

```
and I<>X and I<>Y
```

Result:

```
I
1
2
5
```